# Can anyone explain time nouns and adverbs of time to me?

Tags: grammar

In English, "today" can be a noun or an adverb, but many European languages see it only as an adverb. So, the "today" in "Today is Wednesday." is seen as an adverb.

Can anyone explain time nouns and adverbs of time to me?

Can 最近 be a noun and an adverb?

What part of speech is 上个月？Can it be an adverb?

Can 昨天 be a noun and an adverb?

Comment: "many European languages see it only as an adverb" - which languages?

Answer (score 1):

the "today" in "Today is Wednesday." is a noun……

but I get what did you mean.

“最近”can only be an adverb, it's basically the same as "recently"

"上个月"can both be a noun and an adv. i.e.

noun, 上个月是十一月 last month was November.

adv, 我上个月去了上海 I visited Shanghai last month.

"昨天"is same as “上个月”.

Comment: Is there any reason why words like 今天 and 昨天 are only listed as nouns in the dictionary and 最近 only as a noun or adjective?